# Prove this function is uniformly continuous by verifying the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ property?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, epsilon-delta

$f(x) = \frac{5x}{2x-1}$ on $[1,\infty)$

Here's what I've worked through so far:

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = \left|\frac{5x}{2x-1} - \frac{5y}{2y-1}\right| = \left|\frac{5y-5x}{(2x-1)(2y-1)}\right| <\epsilon.$$

Since we know $2x-1 \geq 1$ and $2y-1 \geq 1$ for $x,y \in [1,\infty)$, then it suffices to say $y-x < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$?

Am I on the right track? Can someone show me where to go from here?

Comment: Yep, take $\delta=\epsilon /5$.

Comment: In fact, if $f$ is continuous on $[1,\infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = L \in \mathbb {R},$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. More formally, using your estimates, you can write: $$\left|\frac{5y - 5x}{(2x - 1)(2y - 1)}\right|\leq \left|5y - 5x\right| = 5|y - x|\leq 5\delta.$$
So, take $$\varepsilon = 5\delta\Rightarrow \delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{5}.$$

Since this estimate doesn't depend on the choice of $x$ and $y$, your continuity is uniform.

Comment: So, after this step, we can confirm the function is uniformly continuous, and we are done?

Comment: Right! You've proven that for any $\varepsilon$, there exists such $\delta$... and you've even found an explicit expression for it.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed help confirming that part.